# Cannot find php-soap package

Tags: php, apache-http-server

I'm having trouble getting SOAP installed on my webserver. I am using SUSE Linux and I have PHP 5.2.6.

I've tried `apt-cache search php-soap` but I am not getting anything. When I try `apt-cache search soap`, I get 3 packages `libsoup`, `libsoup-2_4-1-32bit` and `libsoup-2_4-1`.

I'm trying to get the line `--enable-soap` into my php config file as well. When I try to install it, I get an error "Couldn't find package php-soap".

My `php.ini` file has

```
[soap]
; Enables or disables WSDL caching feature.
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
; Sets the directory name where SOAP extension will put cache files.
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"
; (time to live) Sets the number of second while cached file will be used 
; instead of original one.
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soap support is available natively in PHP 5.2.6. Do a `phpinfo()` and see if you can find the below info (Of course based on your installation some data, like path might be different):

[image]

If you do not have this, you will need to edit php.ini and enable corresponding SO/DLL files.

Open your php.ini file and check for this line:
`;extension=php_soap.dll` (will be .so in linux boxes)

If there is a `;` in front of the line, remove it and save the file. Restart apache, and check `phpinfo()` once again.

Comment: I dont see it on there. I know through searching that there is a soap.so file located at http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=soap.so

Comment: where in php.ini do I have to add enable soap?

Comment: @user: updated answer..

Comment: I dont see the extension=php_soap.so line, there is however an extension_dir=/path/name line. That holds a bunch of .so files. Cant I get a php_soap.so file and place it in there?

Comment: You will first need to add the .so file to that dir. Then in php.ini you will need to add the line `extension = php_soap.so`